# How can i upload a file with utf-8 name in php?

Tags: php, file, upload

we have a file that have persian name, like:

```
ایران.jpg
```

our problem is that php unable to copy or rename this file by orginal name,
meaning if file name does not have fully english character, result is like this:

```
ط§ط´ط±ع©طھ ظ…ظ„غŒ ظ¾ط®ط´ ظپط±ط¢ظˆط±ط¯ظ‡ ظ‡ط§غŒ ظ†ظپطھغŒ-04ط¢ط¨ط§ظ†.jpg
```

some articles recommendation for use of iconv function, like:

```
$fn = iconv("CP-1252", "UTF-8", $file['name']);
```

we use of that method, but the solution not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the correct character set to iconv from which to convert the string. Something like this:

```
$fn = iconv("<persian-character-set>", "UTF-8", $file['name']);
```

You may want to add additional options to the output character set like TRANSLINT and/or IGNORE:

```
$fn = iconv("<persian-character-set>", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $file['name']);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php for details on these options.

Comment: Is there such as thing `<persian-character-set>`? I didn't find anything related to that code.

Comment: That's a place holder for the asker to replace it with the appropiate character set.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing persian-character-set? I do not know!
For example, what kind of text is broken up?

Answer (score 1):

You Should Choose Right Code Page. This Code Works In Windows For Arabic/Persian Names:

```
$newname = iconv("UTF-8", "CP1256//IGNORE","گچپژ");
echo rename("1.txt", $newname);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we have a conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-8, Not ridiculous?

Value of $_FILE['name'] is UTF-8 and we try to set that character-set to UTF-8!!!

Our problem is that we have entered into with utf-8, but saved by unknown encoding!

I think Php is a serious bug, if you think opposite, active persian language in your windows os and try to make a folder by persian character by PHP (like ایران), and use of all method that you think work!

If it was, you did a great job, but if ...